# Using default parameter overloads function

Tags: c++

Good day,

I have the following function declared

scene.h

```
Scene loadScenePrebuilt(SceneType type, const std::filesystem::path& dataDir, Config config = {});
```

and scene.cpp

```
Scene loadScenePrebuilt(SceneType type, const std::filesystem::path& dataDir, Config config){
//random code
}
```

When trying to call the function without the passing a third argument (config) I get this error.

```
C++ more than one instance of overloaded function matches the argument list:         
 one instance is 

Scene loadScenePrebuilt(SceneType type, const std::filesystem::path& dataDir, Config config = {})

and the other is 

Scene loadScenePrebuilt(SceneType type, const std::filesystem::path& dataDir, <error-type> config = <error>)
```

Any idea?

Comment: Is this the only error you are getting? Did you include the `scene.h` header in your cpp?

Comment: @Chronial i did include it and yes its the only error

Comment: It looks like you have a problematic definition of `Config` somewhere.

Comment: @Chronial i know I could just overload but i want to know why cant i do it this way

Comment: @Chronial does it matter if Config includes "scene.h"?

Comment: Depends – do you have `#pragma once` in your headers?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249058/discussion-between-cristian-cutitei-and-chronial).

Comment: I suspect your problem is EITHER with inconsistent definitions of `Config` - for example, it is declared or defined differently in your header and source files, or the definition of the function is not consistent with the declaration.  Either way, the problem is not due to defaulting an argument.    Try providing a [mcve] - i.e. a SMALL (i.e. cut down) but COMPLETE sample of code (with header and source files separate if needed) that someone else can use to get the same symptoms.   That way, other folks will have a fighting chance of being able to offer useful/specific advice.